# adding value to multidimensional array

Tags: vb.net, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array which will hold 3 bits of value and value will be added through a loop by reading from db. When it come this line of code:

`*MenuAccess(.Fields("GROUPNO").Value, .Fields("ITEMNO").Value, .Fields("SUBITEMNO").Value) = OKNO*`

It's hitting error, *'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'*

```
Public MenuAccess(100, 30, 50) As Boolean

Private Sub RtGetMenu_Access()
    Try
        Dim OKNO As Boolean

        Erase MenuAccess

        DBMgr = New cAdodb

        With DBMgr
            .openCnn(cnnSPR)
            .sql(rst1) = "Select * from BSMENU_ACCESS where LEVELCD = '" & Trim(UserTaskLevel) & "' Order by GROUPNO "
            .openRstRead(rst1)

            With .rst(rst1)
                Do While Not .EOF
                    If .Fields("GROUPNO").Value.ToString.Trim <> "" And .Fields("ITEMNO").Value.ToString.Trim <> "" And .Fields("SUBITEMNO").Value.ToString.Trim <> "" Then
                        If .Fields("LEVEL1").Value.ToString.Trim = "Y" Then OKNO = True Else OKNO = False

                        '=> ERROR: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
                        MenuAccess(.Fields("GROUPNO").Value, .Fields("ITEMNO").Value, .Fields("SUBITEMNO").Value) = OKNO

                    End If
                    .MoveNext()
                Loop
            End With

            .closeRst(rst1)
            .closeCnn(rst1)
        End With

        DBMgr = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        If DBMgr.cnn(cnnSPR).State <> 0 Then
            DBMgr.closeCnn(cnnSPR)
            DBMgr = Nothing
        End If
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Option Strict On or Off?

Comment: Obviously one of those fields doesn't exist.  Can't you just use the IDE debugger to determine which one returns null?

Comment: put `.Fields("GROUPNO").Value`, `.Fields("ITEMNO").Value` and `.Fields("SUBITEMNO").Value` into local variables first so that a) you can check for `Nothing` and b) you don't have to access them twice in the `IF` and `MenuAccess` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an initialization for the array

```
Public MenuAccess(100, 30, 50) As Boolean   'Object not initialized in VB.NET
```

Try this

```
Public MenuAccess() As New Boolean(100,30,50)
```

Also convert the fields into integers with `Integer.TryPrase()`

```
Dim i as Integer=-1, j as Integer=-1, k as Integer=-1
Integer.TryParse(.Fields("GROUPNO").Value.ToString(), i)
Integer.TryParse(.Fields("ITEMNO").Value.ToString(), j)
Integer.TryParse(.Fields("SUBITEMNO").Value.ToString(), k)

If i>=0 AndAlso j>=0 AndAlso k>=0 Then
    MenuAccess(i,j,k) = OkNo
End If
```